# How to get reliable docid from Lucene 3.0.3?

Tags: lucene

I would like to get the int docid of a Document I just added to a Lucene index so that I can stick it into a Filter to update a standing query. My documents have a unique external id, so I thought that doing a TermDocs enumeration on the unique id would return the correct document, like this:

```
protected int getDocId(IndexReader reader, String idField, Document doc) throws IOException {
    String id = doc.get(idField);
    TermDocs termDocs = reader.termDocs(new Term(idField, id));
    int docid = -1;
    while (termDocs.next()) {
        docid = termDocs.doc();
        Document aDoc = reader.document(docid);
        String docIdString = aDoc.get(idField);
        System.out.println(docIdString + ": " + docid);
    }
    return docid;
}
```

Unfortunately, this loops and loops, returning the same docIdString and increasing docids.

What is the recommended way to get the docids for newly-added documents so that I could use them in a Filter immediately after the documents are commited?

Comment: While Xodarap's answer below is far better than my code above, the code actually worked -- the problem was that I had duplicate external ids due to iterative debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc Id of a document is *not* the same as the value in your id field. The doc ID is an internal Lucene identifier, which you probably shouldn't access. Your field is just a field - you can call it "ID", but Lucene won't do anything special with it.

Why are you trying to manually update the filter? When you commit, merges can happen etc. so the IDs before will not be the same as the IDs afterwards. (Which is just an example of the general point that you shouldn't rely on Lucene IDs for anything.) So you don't need to just add that one document to the filter, you need to update the whole thing.

To update a cached filter, just run a query for "foo" and use your filter with a `CachingWrapperFilter`.

---

**EDIT**: Because your id field is just a field, you do a search for it like you would anything else:

```
TopDocs results = searcher.Search(new TermQuery(new Term("MyIDField", Id)), 1);
int internalId = results.scoreDocs[0].doc;
```

However, like I said, I think you want to ignore internal IDs. So I would build a filter from a query:

```
BooleanQuery filterQuery = new BooleanQuery(); // or get existing query from cache
filterQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("MyIdField", Id)), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
// add more sub queries for each ID you want in the filter here
Filter myFilter = new CachingWrapperFilter(new QueryWrapperFilter(filterQuery));
```

Comment: I have potentially thousands of standing queries that I would like to evaluate when new docs are added. I don't want to re-run them on the entire collection, since I should be able to do incremental updates on the results from each query that I have cached elsewhere. A CachingWrapperfilter doesn't quite feel right: it'll cache the old results but not the new docs. It seems like docids should have adequate duration for my purposes, but maybe I am misreading their definition.

Comment: @Gene Golovchinsky: Lucene IDs [are not persistent](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#When_is_it_possible_for_document_IDs_to_change.3F). Can you try to manually tell when they change? Sure. But you're taking on a lot of work for minimal gain. I would advise you to be really sure that filtering your way is critical - if you just use caching filters, it will work 99.9999% of the time. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions! I am not actually trying to persist the docids. I am persisting external ids per my sample code above, and at a given point in time -- between any commit() or optimize() calls -- I would like to convert the external ids to their corresponding docids, build a filter & use it. The problem I am having is that I am not getting expected results from the conversion step. Perhaps I am not using the right method of converting external ids to docids.

Comment: @Gene Golovchinsky: I've added some code that might help. As I said, the issue you were having before is that Lucene's doc ID != value of your id field, so you can't enumerate by switching their values.